# Parse.com invalid acl key *unresolved

Tags: acl, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com in my android application.
When I retrieve datas it is ok, but when I try to add something to database it shows an error: invalid acl key.
What I have to add extra when I update database

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code you're using to post to Parse? You may also email feedback@parse.com for support.

Comment: I am getting the same error when doing PushService.subscribe() - Any ideas why this could be so? I am using the Android Starter code with only the modification to enable Push service. Also, the web interface shows that there is something misconfigured - although i have taken care to include all the tags in the xml as pointed in the tutorial.